# regex (preg_match) woes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I just can't get a straight answer from the interwebs today!

I need to validate a form field and check if there are 3 and only 3 (no more, no less), uppercase letters.

My sorry attempts at regex have so far all failed - I thought that

```
/^[A-Z]{3}$/
```

would do the job, but nix. Any takers?!

Comment: what exactly is wrong with the expression you posted? It looks right. Can you provide a bit more of your code so we can see the context; it might be something other than the regex itself that you're getting wrong.

Comment: Could I ask what you get when you run `php -r "var_dump(preg_match('/^[A-Z]{3}$/', 'ABC'));"`? It works fine for me.

Comment: The expression is 100% correct. If something's not working - it's not related to `preg_match()`. Check your variable names, input data, etc.

Comment: Hi all, cheers for this - I'm using it in WordPress to validate an option (selected currency), which I think must be the problem `if( isset( $input['currency'] ) )
  $currency = trim( $input['currency'] );
 if( $currency != preg_match( '/^[A-Z]$/', $currency ) ) {
  add_settings_error(
   'rps_myplugin_currency',
   'rps_myplugin_texterror',
   'Please select a currency',
   'error'
  );
 } else {
  $valid['currency'] = $currency;
 }` Guess I should post on the WP SE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`/^[A-Z]{3}$/`** Will check the string for ...

```
begining_of_the_string->three_and_only_tree_uppercase_letters->end_of_line
```

no other letters are valid in the string with this regexp.

But, I tried it with js regexp. And I think the same for php. Could you provide full code (or at least part of it) of your php script ?